# decision making libraries

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, rule-engine

problem context:

- a list of actions in the system, create this, delete that, edit those etc...
- a list of roles admin, reader, reporter etc...
- a list of emails to send, emergency email, alert email, etc...

I have a decision matrix, which describes when a action happens which role should receive which email.

Ideally I want have a XML file or database tables to config this relationship on the fly.

My question is:

Is there any library to borrow?
Any design patterns to follow?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although it could be overkill for your use-case, you might wish to look into rules engines. There is a [Java API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=94) for such engines. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_94) about this JSR lists a number of implementations. Perhaps one of those provides a rules language that is suitable for your needs.
I believe Drools is quite mature (as implementation; not so much in name :/ ) and it supports a wide variety of languages for describing your rules. The Apache License v2 also makes it suitable for many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a rule engine. The main Java frameworks in that domain are [Openrules](http://openrules.com/) and [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/).